# How to send Multiple array body with API in React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api, expo

[image: that type of API data i want to send with APIs]

> i also want to send the value from radio button but i am new in React
> native that's why i don't know how to send these type of data with API
>
> the value in category is the value that is comes from radio button of
> yes and no. I don't know how to set these radio button value in
> categories[0][value] : 1

[My code in expo snack for Edit](https://snack.expo.dev/@muhammadabdullahrishi/radio-button-with-api-items)

Comment: @GauravRoy can you please solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

this is the payload you need to form, add the respective values to it

```
{
  score_threshold: "",
  categories: [
    {
      sub_category_id: "",
      value: "",
      category_id: "",
      sub_category_name: "",
    },
    {
      sub_category_id: "",
      value: "",
      category_id: "",
      sub_category_name: "",
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: how can i send the radio button value that is '0' and '1'